# how to get the sidebar to stop scrolling at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrolling sidebar on my page that scrolls to any position on the page that the view is currently viewing. I've tried Googling and searching Stack Overflow with no luck to my situation. I've tried other code to get the same results but the other code seems to break the page.

The problem is that when the viewer gets to my footer the sidebar can still scroll past the last element (div tag) and push my footer down virtually extending the length of the page with no content, only the footer. I need to get the sidebar to stop scrolling when the final element (div id) is reached or viewable on the page.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $(".sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

The last elements id is `#return` and the footer has a id of `#footer` the sidebar has a class of `.sidebar`. I don't think the css of the sidebar is the issue but if you need to see that I can provide it.

Comment: HTML? a jsfiddle would be great to understand the problem

Comment: This question needs 100% more jsfiddle